# setBound width and height

Tags: iphone, uiview, uianimation, setbounds

This method gets called after i resize a photo:

```
- (void)correctSize:(UIView*)view{
    //check if the newWidth is rounded by 50
    CGFloat correctWidth = roundf(_lastScale*_lastWidth/XPCollageGridHorizontalStepSize) * XPCollageGridHorizontalStepSize;
    CGFloat correctHeight = roundf(_lastScale*_lastHeight/XPCollageGridVerticalStepSize) * XPCollageGridVerticalStepSize;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f]; 
    [view setBounds:CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x, view.bounds.origin.y, correctWidth, correctHeight)];
    //[view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, correctWidth, correctHeight)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

It rounds the photo size; a width of 66 will be rounded to 50, 178 to 200 etc.
It works fine when i use the setFrame method, but because im also working with rotation i want to work with setBounds.

When i use setBounds, the view will resize, but instead of resizing to a rounded number like 300, it resized to something random as 311.23.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that i have to use the

```
[view setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
```

Now its using the already 'used' matrix and multiplies it with that.

```
    CGFloat correctWidth = roundf(_lastScale*_lastWidth/XPCollageGridHorizontalStepSize) * XPCollageGridHorizontalStepSize;
CGFloat correctHeight = roundf(_lastScale*_lastHeight/XPCollageGridVerticalStepSize) * XPCollageGridVerticalStepSize;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f]; 
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[view setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity]; //!!this line is added!
[view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, correctWidth, correctHeight)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like:

```
// see the values here
NSLog(@"%f", correctWidth);
NSLog(@"%f", correctHeight);
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x, view.bounds.origin.y, correctWidth, correctHeight);
// see the values given
NSLog(@"%f", view.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"%f", view.frame.size.height);
```

Just an idea not sure if it would work